# Laravel 5 on two vps server

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, server, vps

I have a laravel (mysql) project that uses Jobs, cron tasks, etc. I want to configure it on two different vps servers(but one mysql db), but so that the load is distributed evenly. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can define external mysql server in your .env file. 
You just have to change this key: `DB_HOST` (IP address of your mysql server) in your env file.
However, if you want more control, Do take a look at `config/database.php`

Make sure you enable `Allow remote connections` on your mysql-server, To be able to connect with the host.